# Assets not loading in Flutter mini app when launched from superapp

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a superapp consisting of two mini apps, each as a separate Flutter project. The superapp has buttons to launch each mini app using `Navigator.pushReplacement`. However, I am facing an issue where the assets in the mini app are not loading properly when launched from the superapp.

When launching the mini app from its dedicated project, all images are displayed correctly. However, when run from the superapp, `Unable to load asset... Exception. Assets not found` message displayed.

Assets are locatated in miniapp's `assets` folder and not duplicated in superapp project.

The mini apps are included in the superapp's `pubspec.yaml` as follows:

```dart
  petshop:
    path: ../petshop-walking
  petshop_dog_walkers_app:
    path: ../petshop_dog_walkers_app
```

Superapps's `main.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:petshop/main.dart' as customer_app;
import 'package:petshop_dog_walkers_app/main.dart' as dog_walkers_app;
....

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  await configureDependencies();
  // Configuration executed in mini apps' main.dart
  await dog_walkers_app.configureApplication();
  await customer_app.configureApplication();

  runApp(const Application());
}
```

Mini apps are opened by pushing the widget containing MaterialApp to the `Navigator`:

```dart
  Navigator.pushReplacement(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => const customer_app.PetshopApp(),
    ),
  );
```

Is it feasible to structure the application in a way that each app remains a separate Flutter project and is launched from the superapp, or is it necessary to consolidate them into a single Flutter project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem:

### The super app can't access assets bundled with other packages

The assets for the mini app packages are only accessible in the individual packages and so the super app can't find the assets.

When you run the super app and navigate to either one of the mini app packages, you are still in the context of the super app and so when it tries to display the `Image.asset` widget, it can't find the assets since the assets are bundled with the mini app and not the super app.

This is why you can only view the images when you run the mini app by itself.

## Solution:

### Specify the Image.asset's package parameter

From [Image.asset's documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.asset.html):

> To create the widget with an asset from a package, the package
> argument must be provided. For instance, suppose a package called my_icons
> has icons/heart.png . Then to display the image, use:
>
> ```dart
> Image.asset('icons/heart.png', package: 'my_icons')
> ```
>
> Assets used by the package itself should also be displayed using the package argument as above.
>
> - [Assets in packages | Image.asset](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.asset.html#:%7E:text=be%20used%20instead.-,Assets%20in%20packages,-To%20create%20the)

The solution is to specify the `package` parameter of the `Image.asset` constructor.

So if your image code in the `petshop` package was:

```dart
Image.asset(
  'assets/pet_image.png',
)
```

update it to:

```dart
Image.asset(
  'assets/pet_image.png',
  package: 'petshop'
)
```

Now the image from the `petshop` package will be displayed in the super app.

Answer (score -1):

1. List item Ensure that the asset paths in the pubspec.yaml file are

   correct and match the actual file paths.
2. List item Check the indentation of the assets section in the pubspec.yaml

   file. The assets section should be at the same level as the flutter

   section and should be indented by two spaces 32.
3. If the assets are located in a subdirectory, make sure to include the

   subdirectory name in the asset path 4.
4. Try running flutter clean and then flutter pub get to clear the cache

   and retrieve the latest dependencies 32.

Comment: All suggestions listed have been taken into account in the projects.

Comment: problem solve or not

Comment: No, this does not solve the problem. The problem here is about superapp - mini app relation.